# Extract from a data frame column based on a list of indices

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame:

```
df = read.table(text="ID    location    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
M01 1   A   H   H   A   A   B
M02 2   A   H   A   A   A   B
M03 3   A   B   A   A   A   B
M04 4   H   B   H   A   A   B
M05 5   H   B   H   A   A   B
M06 6   A   B   H   A   A   H
M07 7   A   B   H   B   A   H
M08 8   A   B   H   A   A   H
M09 9   A   B   H   A   A   H
M10 10  B   B   H   A   A   H
M11 11  A   B   H   A   A   H
M12 12  A   B   H   A   A   H
M13 13  A   B   H   A   A   H
M14 14  B   B   B   A   A   H
M15 15  B   B   B   A   A   A", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to extract out the values of `df$ID` based on a list of index row numbers of `df`. The list `a` is:

```
a = list(C1 = c(3,   5,   9,   10,  13), C2 = c(2) , 
C3 = c(1,   3,   13 ), C4 =c(6,   7 ), C6 = c(5,   14 ))
```

The expected result is:

```
$C1
[1] "M03" "M05" "M09" "M10" "M13"

$C2
[1] "M02"

$C3
[1] "M01" "M03" "M13"

$C4
[1] "M06" "M07"

$C6
[1] "M05" "M14"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with `lapply` by looping over the `list` and extract the 'ID' based on the index in each of the `list` elements

```
lapply(a, function(x) df$ID[x])
#$C1
#[1] "M03" "M05" "M09" "M10" "M13"

#$C2
#[1] "M02"

#$C3
#[1] "M01" "M03" "M13"

#$C4
#[1] "M06" "M07"

#$C6
#[1] "M05" "M14"
```

Or we can use a compact option with `Map` which does the job

```
Map(`[`, list(df$ID), a)
#[[1]]
#[1] "M03" "M05" "M09" "M10" "M13"

#[[2]]
#[1] "M02"

#[[3]]
#[1] "M01" "M03" "M13"

#[[4]]
#[1] "M06" "M07"

#[[5]]
#[1] "M05" "M14"

nchar("Map(`[`, list(df$ID), a)")
#[1] 24
```

#### Benchmarks

Here, the benchmarks are based on a `vector` ('v1') with a `list` ('a1').

```
v1 <- paste0("M", 1:1e6)
```

If it is a `data.frame` column (`v1 <- someDat$ID`) to avoid repeated extractions.

```
set.seed(24)
a1 <- lapply(1:1e4, function(i) sample(1:1e6, sample(1e3), replace=FALSE))

system.time(relist(v1[unlist(a1, use.names = FALSE)], a1))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.81    0.03    0.84 


system.time(lapply(a1, function(x) v1[x]))
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.36    0.00    0.36 

system.time(Map(`[`, list(v1), a1))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.35    0.00    0.34
```

**NOTE**: Removed the `{}` (which we overlooked earlier), but still there is not much change in the benchmarks.  As we stated earlier, it is better to create a vector object (`v1 <- someDat$ID`) and use it to check benchmarks instead of extracting the column everytime.  In that respect, this benchmark serves the **accurate** purpose of benchmarking.

Answer (score 8):

You could unlist the `a` list, index the data values, then `relist` it with itself as the skeleton.

```
relist(df$ID[unlist(a)], a)
# $C1
# [1] "M03" "M05" "M09" "M10" "M13"
#
# $C2
# [1] "M02"
#
# $C3
# [1] "M01" "M03" "M13"
#
# $C4
# [1] "M06" "M07"
#
# $C6
# [1] "M05" "M14"
```

Additionally, we could get an increase in speed if we drop the names in `unlist`.

```
relist(df$ID[unlist(a, use.names = FALSE)], a)
```

**Note:**

The  benchmarks in the other answer are misleading.  Here is a **more accurate** benchmark, showing the actual code from the other answer that uses `$` extraction on every iteration and removing the unnecessary `{}` brackets around my expression ...

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = paste0("M", 1:1e6))
set.seed(24)
a1 <- lapply(1:1e4, function(i) sample(1:1e6, sample(1e3), replace=FALSE))

system.time(relist(df$v1[unlist(a1, use.names = FALSE)], a1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.485   0.004   0.489 
system.time(lapply(a1, function(x) df$v1[x]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.39    0.00    0.39
```